# window.getSelection() sometime get range is not true

Tags: javascript, html

```html
 <div  :class="fullScreen?'full_container':'container'">
            <div :class="fullScreen?'full_editor_container':'editor_container'"  id="editor_content" style="position:relative;">
                <div id="editor_container"  class="editor_container_content" ref="content" style= "width:100%;height:100%;" contenteditable  refs='content' @mousedown="onFocus"  @blur='onBlur'  @mouseup='saveCurrentRange' @keyup='saveCurrentRange' @mouseout='saveCurrentRange' @click="switchHistory = true"> </div>
                <div class="placeholder"  v-show="editorContent == ''" :style="placeholderColor?`color:${placeholderColor}`:null">{{placeholder}}</div>
            </div>
```

I want to make a text editor, so I use `window.getSelection()` to get the text that mouse selected.
But sometimes, I get weird results.
For example, if I select the text "`hahhahahhahahahahhahahahahahhahahahahhahaha`", when I log the current Selection I get

> ```
> anchorNode: text  
> anchorOffset: 3  
> focusNode: text  
> focusOffset: 43  
> isCollapsed: false  
> rangeCount: 1  
> type: "Range"  
> baseNode: text  
> baseOffset: 3  
> extentNode: text  
> extentOffset: 43
> ```

when the `anchorOffset` should actually have been `0`.

Comment: Please include the HTML markup. It is probable that the textNode has invisible characters like `\n` which wouldn't get rendered, but would still be present.

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: [edit] your question so it includes your HTML in a [mcve].

Comment: ok,i already add my html code